# Convert Dictionary<MyType>.ValueCollection to IList<MyType>

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'm using a `Dictionary<int, MyType>` in a class.  That class implements a interface that requires an `IList<MyType>` to be returned.  Is there a simple way to to cast the one to the other (without copying the entire thing)?

My current solution follows:

```
private IList<MyType> ConvertToList(Dictionary<int, MyType>.ValueCollection valueCollection)
{
    List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();
    list.AddRange(valueCollection);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Every solution posted so far involves copying the entire collection.  **Read the question**.

Comment: @SLaks: I addressed this directly in my answer... (which still involves copying, though)

Comment: Is there any relevance for the keyType "int", or is it an arbitrary type?

Comment: @Janko `int` is the 'key' field for the type.  It is a property on the type as well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll need to do a copy, but this is probably a good thing.  In C# 2, your current code is almost the cleanest you can make.  It would be improved by directly constructing your list off your values (`List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>(valueCollection);`), but a copy will still be required.

Using LINQ with C# 3, however, you would be able to do:

```
myDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

That being said, I would not (probably) try to avoid the copy.  Returning a copy of your values tends to be safer, since it prevents the caller from causing problems if they attempt to modify your collection.  By returning a copy, the caller can do `list.Add(...)` or `list.Remove(...)` without causing your class problems.

---

Edit:  Given your comment below, if all you want is an `IEnumerable<T>` with a Count, you can just return `ICollection<T>`.  This **is** directly implemented by `ValueCollection`, which means you can just return your dictionary's values directly, with no copying:

```
private ICollection<MyType> ConvertToList(Dictionary<int, MyType>.ValueCollection valueCollection)
{
    return valueCollection;
}
```

(Granted, this method becomes really useless in this case - but I wanted to demonstrate it for you...)

Comment: @Slaks: Hence the next sentence: "You can directly construct your list off your values," ;)  That's not much better, although since it's an ICollection<T>, it will be more efficient (since count is known in advance).

Comment: @Slaks: That better?  I made it more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer.  The ICollection interface fit my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
Dictionary<int, MyType> dlist = new Dictionary<int, MyType>();
IList<MyType> list = new List<MyType>(dlist.Values);
```

Comment: This still copies the collection.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

A dictionary (including its `Values` collection) is an inherently unordered collections; its order will change based on the hashcodes of its keys.  This is why `ValueCollection` doesn't implement `IList<T>` in the first place.

If you **really** wanted to, you could make a wrapper class that implements `IList` and wraps the `ValueCollection`, using a `foreach` loop in the indexer.  However, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not picky about the order.  What I want is IEnumerable with a count.  If there's a better Interface, let me know.

Comment: It impelemts ICollection so use that. @SLaks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor:

```
public IList<MyType> MyValues
{
    get { return new List<MyType>(myDictionary.Values); }
}
```

(Edited to remove an assertion I'm not 100% sure on.)

Comment: This still creates a copy of the collection.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ToList()` method:

`myDictionary.Values.ToList();`

It is available importing `Linq`: `using System.Linq;`