# Xamarin.iOS - System.Linq ToArray - no accessible method

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios

I am trying to convert a Dictionary to NSDictionary.

```
document = NSDictionary\<string, object\>(); // with some data of course
```

The way I am doing this is:

```
NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject> iosDoc = NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(
  document.Values.ToArray(),  
  document.Keys.ToArray()
);
```

And the error I get is the following:

> Error CS1061: 'Dictionary<string, object>.ValueCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no accessible extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, object>.ValueCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

> Error CS1061: 'Dictionary<string, object>.KeyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no accessible extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, object>.KeyCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

This has worked in a previous project and Visual Studio recognises this method but the code doesn't compile.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq;` in your using statements?

Comment: Yeah, here are my usings:

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase.Auth;
using Firebase.CloudFirestore;
using Foundation;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Dictionary<MyType>.ValueCollection to IList<MyType>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540555/convert-dictionarymytype-valuecollection-to-ilistmytype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert from `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`, you could try the code below. It works well for me. I tested on ios 15.4 with xcode 13.3.

```
 var document = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"A", "a"},
                {"B", "b"},
                {"C", "c"},
                {"D", "d"},
                {"E", "e"}
            };

        var iosDoc = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(document.Values.ToArray(), document.Keys.ToArray());
```